# Give two background colors to a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have two separate backgrounds behind my div `.login-section`

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="login-container">
  <div class="login-section"></div>
</div>
```

I want to give two different background color to the `.login-container` div as shown in the image

[image]

Comment: Please read the guidance on "[ask]" and "[mcve]," and then [edit] your question to include relevant information such as the HTML and CSS you're already using in order that we can recreate your problem in order to help you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use linear-gradient background.

```css
.bg {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(#03a2e8 0%, #03a2e8 40%, #eeeeef 40%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 49%, rgba(5,193,255,1) 50%, rgba(5,193,255,1) 100%);

Gradient generator http://angrytools.com/gradient/